# How can I fill in/color a transparent vector path in AI CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, path, shapes

Thank you for taking the time.
I'm actually new to AI and I'm having a trouble filling in a vector path that's transparent on the inside. I have attached a pictuare of the shape that I want to fill in, I tried changing the color from the fill box, but the border color changed instead of the inside.

[image: shape-recolor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve that, depending on your usage. Here's one way:

- hit <kbd>A</kbd> and Alt-Click the inner line of the 'O'
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> this takes the inside of the 'O' and creates a new object of the same shape and in the same position.
- With this new object selected you can now choose a new fill color.

Answer (score 1):

- Select the O
- Choose `Object > Compound path > Release` from the menu

Both shapes are then standard shapes.. fill them however you'd like.

Comment: While the other methods work, this is the only truly right solution. Tge reason is that this builds the right kind of structure (that is imprevious to conflation artifacts) that is the lightest possible one. If you dont understand why this is you should cogitate on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Select your shape and fill its interior with the Shape Builder tool. It creates a new object that can have a fill and a stroke. You can select them afterwards or just before clicking the interior of the O.